# Has a Kendo UI Widget been applied to a DOM object (to avoid duplication)

Tags: kendo-ui

This function display the dialog. While opening, it creates also a kendo editor. The problem is that, when the dialog is closed then reopened, the editor is duplicated.

```
function openChangeProjectStatusPopup(popupElementName) {
  $("#" + popupElementName).dialog({
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $('#changePhaseTextArea').kendoEditor();
    },
    close: function () {
    }
  });
}
```

To avoid duplication, I should do a check like this

```
if(changePhaseTextArea is a not already a kendoeditor){
   $('#changePhaseTextArea').kendoEditor();
}
```

I've checked the kendo websites, I can't find where one can check the type of the object.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is asking for the widget object that is referenced via `data("kendoEditor")` or in general `data("kendo_<String>")` where `<String>` is the name of the widget.

For your code example:

```
var elem = $("#changePhaseTextArea");
if (!elem.data("kendoEditor")) {
    $('#changePhaseTextArea').kendoEditor();
}
```

Comment: It's amazing to see how it works. A new opening to new possibilities. Thank you.